# Activity Indicator not visibile

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am having a weird issue that is I need to animate an `Activity Indicator` When I select a `Cell` from `CollectionView`.

My problem is while Debugging the code with Breakpoint ,`Activity Indicator` is animating but without breakpoint when running the app `Activity Indicator` is not showing up. Kindly help.

```
loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
loading.frame = CGRectMake(round((self.view.frame.size.width - 25) / 2), round((self.view.frame.size.height - 25) / 2), 25, 25);

[self.view addSubview:loading];
[loading startAnimating];
NSString *videoStringUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"source"]];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      VideoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:videoStringUrl];
      AVURLAsset *sourceAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:VideoURL options:nil];
      CMTime duration = sourceAsset.duration;
      float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
      if (seconds<4) {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Edit" sender:self];
      }
      else
      {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Trimmer" sender:self];
      }

});});
```

Comment: can u show ur code

Comment: I have a feeling this is threading, show the entire method you are starting / stoping the animation in

Comment: still need the entire method, name and all, for some reason you are making a background thread then just making a main thread inside it ?

Comment: looks like this [loading startAnimating]; line of code runs not in the main thread, but should.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 does that really be the reason for not loading ??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `dispatch_get_global_queue` not used at all !

Everything runs on main thread and it is huge burden to it.  Remove both 'dispatch_async' blocks **Beacuse only in Main thread, ui elements are gets updated.**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   //Keep rest of code lines here...
   });
});
```

If still you cannot see Activity Indicator, then try to move heavy task to background thread and show the activity indicator as in

```
 loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
loading.frame = CGRectMake(round((self.view.frame.size.width - 25) / 2), round((self.view.frame.size.height - 25) / 2), 25, 25);

[self.view addSubview:loading];
[loading startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    //Heavy tasks at background thread
      NSString *videoStringUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"source"]];
      VideoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:videoStringUrl];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

     //After completion stop animating activity indicator 
      [loading stopAnimating];

        AVURLAsset *sourceAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:VideoURL options:nil];
        CMTime duration = sourceAsset.duration;
        float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
        if (seconds<4) {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Edit" sender:self];
        }
        else
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Trimmer" sender:self];
        }

    });});
```

Comment: its not working,My requirement is to load an indicator when a cell from a collectionview is pressed,So I kept the loading indicator in DidSelect method

Answer (score 1):

You are changing queue so frequently give some delay to settle it.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC),     dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      //Keep rest of code lines here...
   });
});
```

Comment: I know this is not the answer just a trick, but I can not predict the multithreading behaviour without seeing the code flow/ design. Give up vote if it is working for you :)